# Insertar textoo en array con número negativo en laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

tengo que traducir esto:

```
<?php
    $estado["-1"]=trans('web.locked');
    $estado["0"]=trans('web.desactivado');
    $estado["1"]=trans('web.activado');
?>
```

A javascript, para ponerlo en una llamada ajax de jquery

```
 '<td>'+estado[response.empreses[i]['status']]+'</td>\n' +
```

Lo intenté de ésta forma:

```
var estado = [
           '{{trans('web.desactivado')}}',
           '{{trans('web.activado')}}',
           '{{trans('web.locked')}}'
       ];
```

Pero la opción locked me sale undefined.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿y cuál es el valor de `i`?, faltó que lo agregaras en tu código JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo resolví, solo cuestión de sintaxis, ésta es la solución:

```
var estado = [];

        estado['-1'] =  '{{trans('web.locked')}}';
        estado['1'] =  '{{trans('web.activado')}}';
        estado['0'] =  '{{trans('web.desactivado')}}';
```

Era para cambiar los números que salían en la respuesta ajax para mi tabla de resultados por el texto que le correspondía.